# What does clr!_EH_epilog3 means?

Tags: debugging, garbage-collection, clr

I have a deadlock in applicating. 
My research on dump gave followed results:
1) there are several threads:

```
0:022> !threads
ThreadCount:      23
UnstartedThread:  1
BackgroundThread: 21
PendingThread:    1
DeadThread:       0
Hosted Runtime:   no
                                                                         Lock  
       ID OSID ThreadOBJ    State GC Mode     GC Alloc Context  Domain   Count Apt Exception
   0    1  bc8 01108a10     26020 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 01102c30 0     STA 
   2    2 1380 011169c0     2b220 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 01102c30 0     MTA (Finalizer) 
   4    3  a1c 011c9c28   102a220 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 01102c30 0     MTA (Threadpool Worker) 
   5    4 13dc 011a1118   1020220 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 01102c30 0     Ukn (Threadpool Worker) 
   7    7 11dc 0793ff00     20220 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 01102c30 0     Ukn 
   8    8  e08 0798a910     20220 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 01102c30 0     Ukn 
   9    9 1314 07a11800     20220 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 01102c30 0     Ukn 
  10   10  c40 07a2ee40     20220 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 01102c30 0     Ukn 
  11   11  dfc 07a1cf68     20220 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 01102c30 0     Ukn 
  12   12  ed8 07a8bcb0     20220 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 01102c30 0     Ukn 
  19   13 1328 07a8c1f8     20220 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 01102c30 0     Ukn 
  14   14 1114 07a9c970     20220 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 01102c30 0     Ukn 
  15   15 10ac 07a8d0f8     20220 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 01102c30 0     Ukn 
  16   16  ad8 07a8d918     20220 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 01102c30 0     Ukn 
  17   17  640 07a72d98     20220 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 01102c30 0     Ukn 
  18   18  620 07a72308     20220 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 01102c30 0     Ukn 
  13   19 1198 07a70de8     20220 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 01102c30 0     Ukn 
  20   20  594 07a6f380   1029220 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 01102c30 0     MTA (Threadpool Worker) 
  21   21 116c 07a6f8c8   1039220 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 01102c30 0     Ukn (Threadpool Worker) 
  22   24  fb4 0c7c2340   1029220 Cooperative 00000000:00000000 01102c30 2     MTA (GC) (Threadpool Worker) 
  23    5  b10 0a9c6608   8039220 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 01102c30 0     Ukn (Threadpool Completion Port) 
  24    6  164 0c7c6298   8029220 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 01102c30 0     MTA (Threadpool Completion Port) 
  26   23  e9c 07a71330      1600 Preemptive  00000000:00000000 01102c30 0     Ukn
```

2) Threads 0, 9, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21 and 23 are waiting for GC is finished. As they have similar callstack. Like this:

```
00 048fec90 76c12cc7 000001bc 00000000 00000000 ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
01 048fed04 74d74b85 000001bc ffffffff 00000000 KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x99 (FPO: [SEH])
02 048fed34 74d74bcc 00000000 3629c685 00000000 clr!CLREventWaitHelper2+0x31 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
03 048fed84 74d74b4f 00000000 3629c6bd 0a9c6608 clr!CLREventWaitHelper+0x2a (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
04 048fedbc 74e52c82 ffffffff 00000000 00000000 clr!CLREventBase::WaitEx+0x152 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
05 048fedd0 74e55e8d 00000000 3629c6e1 0a9c6608 clr!WKS::GCHeap::WaitUntilGCComplete+0x34 (FPO: [1,0,0])
06 048fee20 74d698cc 00000005 048fee64 ffffffff clr!Thread::RareDisablePreemptiveGC+0x1dc (FPO: [0,13,0])
...
```

3) Callstack of the thread 22 looks like is waits for something:

```
00 0a26e730 76c12cc7 000001c8 00000000 00000000 ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
01 0a26e7a4 74d74b85 000001c8 ffffffff 00000000 KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x99 (FPO: [SEH])
02 0a26e7d4 74d74bcc 00000000 3880c325 00000000 clr!CLREventWaitHelper2+0x31 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
03 0a26e824 74d74b4f 00000000 3880c35d 07a71330 clr!CLREventWaitHelper+0x2a (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
04 0a26e85c 74ef33a9 ffffffff 00000000 00000000 clr!CLREventBase::WaitEx+0x152 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
05 0a26e878 74ef33da 3880c3b9 753b11d0 00000000 clr!WKS::gc_heap::create_bgc_thread+0x4e (FPO: [0,0,0])
06 0a26e8b8 74e4f783 00000010 00000000 00000003 clr!WKS::gc_heap::garbage_collect+0x38a (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
07 0a26e8e0 74e52be0 00000000 00000000 0c7c2380 clr!WKS::GCHeap::GarbageCollectGeneration+0x203 (FPO: [2,5,4])
08 0a26e904 74e4f0db 00000000 0b48bb5c 0c7c2380 clr!WKS::gc_heap::try_allocate_more_space+0x157 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
09 0a26e91c 74e4f24f 00000000 00000010 010fd130 clr!WKS::gc_heap::allocate_more_space+0x18 (FPO: [1,0,0])
0a 0a26e934 74d692e6 00000010 00000010 00000002 clr!WKS::GCHeap::Alloc+0x4f (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
...
```

Dumpstack of this thread looks like this:

```
ChildEBP RetAddr  Caller, Callee
0a26e730 76c12cc7 KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x99, calling ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject
0a26e7a4 74d74b85 clr!CLREventWaitHelper2+0x31
0a26e7d4 74d74bcc clr!CLREventWaitHelper+0x2a, calling clr!CLREventWaitHelper2
0a26e824 74d74b4f clr!CLREventBase::WaitEx+0x152, calling clr!CLREventWaitHelper
0a26e83c 74df70ea clr!Thread::StartThread+0x71, calling clr!_EH_epilog3
0a26e85c 74ef33a9 clr!WKS::gc_heap::create_bgc_thread+0x4e, calling clr!CLREventBase::WaitEx
0a26e878 74ef33da clr!WKS::gc_heap::garbage_collect+0x38a, calling clr!WKS::gc_heap::create_bgc_thread
0a26e894 74e52b98 clr!WKS::gc_heap::wait_for_bgc_high_memory+0x111, calling clr!__security_check_cookie
0a26e8b8 74e4f783 clr!WKS::GCHeap::GarbageCollectGeneration+0x203, calling clr!WKS::gc_heap::garbage_collect
0a26e8e0 74e52be0 clr!WKS::gc_heap::try_allocate_more_space+0x157, calling clr!WKS::GCHeap::GarbageCollectGeneration
0a26e904 74e4f0db clr!WKS::gc_heap::allocate_more_space+0x18, calling clr!WKS::gc_heap::try_allocate_more_space
0a26e91c 74e4f24f clr!WKS::GCHeap::Alloc+0x4f, calling clr!WKS::gc_heap::allocate_more_space
0a26e934 74d692e6 clr!Alloc+0x54
0a26e954 74d6940f clr!AllocateObject+0x94, calling clr!Alloc
0a26e970 74d73bf6 clr!ObjIsInstanceOfNoGC+0x13d, calling clr!MethodTable::CanCastToClassNoGC
0a26e98c 74d62adc clr!HelperMethodFrame::Push+0x10, calling clr!GetThread
0a26e994 74d694a3 clr!JIT_New+0x6b, calling clr!AllocateObject
0a26e9cc 0825f15f (MethodDesc 08201884 +0x97 NHibernate.Loader.Loader.InstanceNotYetLoaded(System.Data.IDataReader, Int32, NHibernate.Persister.Entity.ILoadable, NHibernate.Engine.EntityKey, NHibernate.LockMode, System.String, NHibernate.Engine.EntityKey, System.Object, System.Collections.IList, NHibernate.Engine.ISessionImplementor)), calling 0757329e
0a26e9e4 0825ec49 (MethodDesc 0820186c +0x129 NHibernate.Loader.Loader.GetRow(System.Data.IDataReader, NHibernate.Persister.Entity.ILoadable[], NHibernate.Engine.EntityKey[], System.Object, NHibernate.Engine.EntityKey, NHibernate.LockMode[], System.Collections.IList, NHibernate.Engine.ISessionImplementor)), calling (MethodDesc 08201884 +0 NHibernate.Loader.Loader.InstanceNotYetLoaded(System.Data.IDataReader, Int32, NHibernate.Persister.Entity.ILoadable, NHibernate.Engine.EntityKey, NHibernate.LockMode, System.String, NHibernate.Engine.EntityKey, System.Object, System.Collections.IList, NHibernate.Engine.ISessionImplementor))
...
```

So, I've looked into source code of the coreclr and found out, that at the first step `gc_heap::create_bgc_thread` started a working thread and waits (INFINITE) untill this sthead will be started:

```
#else // FEATURE_REDHAWK

    Thread* current_bgc_thread;

    gh->bgc_thread = SetupUnstartedThread(FALSE);
    if (!(gh->bgc_thread))
    {
        goto cleanup;
    }

    current_bgc_thread = gh->bgc_thread;
    if (!current_bgc_thread->CreateNewThread (0, &(gh->bgc_thread_stub), gh))
    {
        goto cleanup;
    }

    current_bgc_thread->SetBackground (TRUE, FALSE);

    // wait for the thread to be in its main loop, this is to detect the situation
    // where someone triggers a GC during dll loading where the loader lock is
    // held.
    current_bgc_thread->StartThread();

#endif // FEATURE_REDHAWK

    {
        dprintf (2, ("waiting for the thread to reach its main loop"));
        // In chk builds this can easily time out since
        // now we need to set the thread up into a managed thead. 
        // And since it's a managed thread we also need to make sure that we don't
        // clean up here and are still executing code on that thread (it'll
        // trigger all sorts of asserts.
        //DWORD res = gh->background_gc_create_event.Wait(20,FALSE);
        DWORD res = gh->background_gc_create_event.Wait(INFINITE,FALSE);
        if (res == WAIT_TIMEOUT)
```

So, it looks like create_bgc_thread waits for a thread, that can't be resumed (`Thread::StartThread` just calls `::ResumeThread`).

There is a strange line in the dumpstack, which i don't really understand:

```
0a26e83c 74df70ea clr!Thread::StartThread+0x71, calling clr!_EH_epilog3
```

What does it means? Is it an exception/crash of clr?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [Microsoft doc on prologs and epilogs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/prolog-and-epilog) that might help your understanding.

Based on this [blog on Microsoft exception handling](http://www.openrce.org/articles/full_view/21) it looks like `_EH_epilog3` is built-in epilog function.

My guess is that possibly that thread threw an exception which is not handled?

Comment: I suppose, that not handeled exception should crash the application but there was no crash. Application just spopped working and "hang" for a while.
And if there was an exception, do you know, how could i find out the type out that exception?

Comment: Going back to the overall problem you're having with it crashing. The problem thread is when it is trying to allocate memory. Maybe it's out of memory or has some other kind of problem with GC?